# Javascript does not run on android and ripple emulator

Tags: javascript, android, ajax

i have this script i've include on my page from source which work perfectly in browswers but fails to work on android emulator:

```
$(window).load(function(){             
      var url = window.location.search.substring(1);          
      $('#mydiv').load('real_news.asp?'+url);
});
```

and here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.3.1 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title>Untitled Document</title>
     <style type="text/css">
         body,td,th {
             font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
             font-size: 12px;
             color: #000;
         }
     </style>
     <link href="../jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="../jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <script src="../jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="try">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="mydiv" data-role="content"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you call this page in a Browser (if so: which?) or in a WebView? If you run it in a WebView, you need to enable JavaScript first:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

And maybe:

```
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: i've got javascript enabled in my browsers? and please where should i place the code? in the head or body